# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un bucle infinito en el programa Python

Tags: python

¿Cómo poder hacer un bucle infinito en una lasta de números en Python?

Comment: `while (True): <hacer algo>`

Comment: `while True: ...`

Comment: Hola ÁNGEL2348, bienvenido, podrías aclararnos que es lo que quieres conseguir, ya que en general, tratamos de evitar los bucles infinitos, y si no sabes como crearlos, dudo que sepas como salir de el, por otro lado hablas de una lista de números... cual?, porfi, agrega la info pertinente para que podamos darte una mejor respuesta, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, 

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 2):

De manera general, no es conveniente la creación de un bucle infinito en un programa, pues tarde o temprano acabará por fallar al llegar toda la memoria RAM del ordenador en el que se esté ejecutando.

Crear un bucle infinito que imprima continuamente la oración 'Hello World!' sería tan sencillo como escribir lo siguiente:

```
while True:   
    print('Hello World!')
```

Las dos líneas de código anterior generarían un bucle infinito.

Sin embargo, como he dicho, esto pocas veces suele ser útil en un programa destinado a una aplicación en el mundo real.

---

-- **Bucle infinito con condicional** --

Una opción que tienes sería crear un bucle infinito, que finalize cuando el código que haya dentro del bucle haya cumplido alguna condición.

Un ejemplo sería este:

```
contador = 0
while True:

    contador +=1
    print(contador)

    if contador == 5: # Si 'contador' es igual a 5, se romperá
        break         # la ejecución del bucle while.
    else:             # En caso contrario,
        continue      # el bucle continua.
```

Otra manera de hacer la misma función, pero con algo menos de código sería escribir la condición en el bucle while, de la siguiente manera:

```
contador = 0
while contador != 5:  # Si 'contador' almacena un valor diferente a 5,
                      # el bucle seguirá ejecutándose
    contador +=1
    print(contador)
```